# Label collection rendered incorrectly

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the following form where `questionaire.Questions` is a collection of `QuestionType` which is just a yes/no `<select>`.

Here's what the twig looks like:

**Expected:**

```
    {{ form_start(questionaire) }}
    {% for question in questionaire.Questions %}
        <div class="question">
            {{ form_label(question) }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(question) }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form_end(questionaire) }}
```

However it gets rendered like this:

```
        <div class="question">
            //This is where I want the label. But instead I get this:
            <label></label>//Unsure why it's empty. Maybe it's questionaire.Question's label?
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>lorem ipsum...</label> //Wrong place. Label gets rendered here instead.
            <select>...</select> //Selection widget is correctly rendered.
        </div>
```

I think the label is getting rendered along with the widget. Here's my QuestionType just in case.

```
class QuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $question = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $form->add('Answer', 'choice', array(
                    'label' => $question->getQuestion(),
                    'choices' => array(
                        '' => 'Select One',
                        'Yes',
                        'No'
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
        );
    }
...
}
```

How can I get the label to where I want it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the form_widget and form_label for the answer type

```
{{ form_label(question.Answer) }}
{{ form_widget(question.Answer) }}
```

Comment: And, of course. I knew this but I was calling the wrong method this whole time! Such a silly mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the block question_row in a form theme, and use {{ form(questionaire_form) }} to render the entire form.

**Acme/DemoBundle/Form/Type/QuestionType.php**

```
// ...

public function getName(){
    return 'question';
}

// ...
```

**Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php**

```
// ...

public function questionaireAction(){

    $form = $this->createForm(new BriefQuestionaireType());

    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Default:brief_questionaire.html.twig', array(
        'questionaire_form' => $form->createView()
    ));

}

// ...
```

**Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Default/brief_questionaire.html.twig**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Questionaire</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% form_theme questionaire_form 'AcmeDemoBundle:Form:form.html.twig' %}
        {{ form(questionaire_form) }}
    </body>
</html>
```

**Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Form/form.html.twig**

We create a block named [block_prefix]_row, where block_prefix is derived from getName() in QuestionType above. When this form theme is used, all QuestionType rows are rendered this way.

```
{% block question_row %}
    <div class="question">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_error(form) }}              
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks but the question had already been answered around half an hour ago :D I'm sure it'll help the next poor soul though :)

Comment: Thought it might be worth showing an example using {% form_theme ... %} and {{ form(...) }}. Using them makes pages a little easier to maintain.